# What does \b really mean in Ruby regular expressions?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a file with phrases such as "Canyon St / 27th Way" that I am trying to turn into "Canyon St and 27th Way" with Ruby regular expressions.

I used `file = file.gsub(/(\b) \/ (\b)/, "#{$1} and #{$2}")` to make the match, but I am a little stumped about what \b really means and why $1 contains all of the characters before the word boundary that precedes the slash and why $2 contains all of the characters after the word boundary starting the next word.

Usually, I expect that whatever is in parentheses in a regular expression would be in $1 and $2, but I am not sure what parentheses around a word boundary would really mean because there really is nothing between the transition from a word character to a white space character.

Comment: use .split() function to split on '/'

Comment: Is there another regex match prior to this line ?

Comment: There are many lines that need this type of match in the file, and I do not want to match dates in the 5/15/2015 format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $1 and $2 are not actually related to your regex match: a method's arguments are evaluated before the method is  called, so

```
"#{$1} and #{$2}"
```

Is evaluated before the regex is matched against your string. If you haven't done earlier regex matches then these variables will be nil, so you're actually doing

```
file = file.gsub(/(\b) \/ (\b)/, " and ")
```

that is you are replacing a slash surrounded by spaces by "and", also surrounded by spaces. $1 and $2 will be updated to be empty strings, and so you'll see the same behaviour when you process the next string.

Comment: See my comment under Rob's answer. How do you explain _that_? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev not sure what you mean - behaves exactly as I would expect.

Comment: Must be I'm confused :)

Answer (score 8):

The parentheses aren't doing anything in this context. You could get the same result using `/\b \/ \b/`.

I think you are getting a little confused by `$1` and `$2`. Those aren't actually doing anything either. They are nil because they are matching nothing (just a word boundry). What you have written is the logical equivalent of `.gsub(/\b \/ \b/, " and ")`

Comment: Nice theory. Contradicts experimental facts, though (I think): http://pastebin.com/Wa85vNjG

Comment: @Ajedi32 No, his result string contains that text because he is only replacing the word boundries and ``` / ``` with and, the other text is not affected. ```$1``` and ```$2``` are empty.

Comment: @RobWagner: my apologies. Time for bed :)

Comment: You'd have to use the block form of gsub in your latter argument - the substitution string, as all method arguments is evaluated before gsub is called

Comment: @FrederickCheung is correct. I will remove that section from my response.

Comment: No one has pointed out that the word boundaries are completely unnecessary? `"Canyon St / 27th Way".gsub(/\//,'and') #=> "Canyon St and 27th Way"`

Comment: @engineersmnky: there is a deleted answer about this

Comment: I will leave my answer for the sake of the discussion, but I would advise that you accept @FrederickCheung's as his is more complete.

Comment: @RobWagner Might want to put some example code in the question. A short example illustrating what you meant by "you could get the same result using /\b \/ \b/" would really help make this answer a lot clearer.

Comment: @engineersmnky: It's unnecessary in this case.  But if a single string were the only case, it wouldn't make sense to use a regex at all.  :)  It wouldn't work the same on, say, the string `"(a + b) / (c + d)"`. (Though the use of `\b` might in fact be a lurking bug.)

Answer (score 0):

> \b - Matches word boundaries when outside brackets; backspace (0x08) when inside brackets

See https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors

[There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

1. Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
2. After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
3. Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Examples of 1 & 2:

```
'island is'.gsub(/is/, 'IS')     => "ISland IS"
'island is'.gsub(/\bis/, 'IS')   => "ISland IS"
'island is'.gsub(/is\b/, 'IS')   => "island IS"
'island is'.gsub(/\bis\b/, 'IS') => "island IS"
```

Examples of 3:

```
'this island is beautiful'.gsub(/is/, 'IS')     => "thIS ISland IS beautiful"
'this island is beautiful'.gsub(/\bis/, 'IS')   => "this ISland IS beautiful"
'this island is beautiful'.gsub(/is\b/, 'IS')   => "thIS island IS beautiful"
'this island is beautiful'.gsub(/\bis\b/, 'IS') => "this island IS beautiful"
```

The best way to do what you want is a simple substitution:

```
'Canyon St / 27th Way'.gsub(/\//,'and') => "Canyon St and 27th Way"
```

A rather bloated way would include capturing and referencing:

```
'Canyon St / 27th Way'.gsub(/(.*) \/ (.*)/, "\\1 and \\2") => "Canyon St and 27th Way"
```